# How to output non-terminated char array to stdout

Tags: c, io, output

I've got an array of characters which could contain a NULL character.
The array is not null-terminated, but I do know it's length.

**Question**
How do I output this exact array (including null characters) and nothing else (no trailing \n) to stdout? Unfortunately, I am not allowed to output one character at a time.

Comment: I need to get my Turing machine to finish first, then I can answer this. Srsly though. I has definite-length?

Comment: Is there some reason why you can not just use fwrite ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char buffer[SIZE];

if(fwrite(buffer, 1, SIZE, stdout) != SIZE) {
    perror("fwrite");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
size_t rt = write(STDOUT_FILENO, &yourCharArray, SIZE_OF_YOUR_ARRAY);
```

where `rt` is the number of the actual written bytes

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
char arr[SIZE]
fwrite(arr, sizeof(char), SIZE, stdout)
```

fwrite is in stdio.h

Comment: Thanks @PaulR. Corrected the answer.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is redundant as it is 1 by definition - see @Charlie's answer

Comment: @PaulR, Right, but its for the sake of clarity. There is no runtime overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Though hard to find if you're a C newbie, the answer turns out to be very easy.

C sees stdout as a file, which means you can simply use fwrite to accomplish this.

```
fwrite(CHAR_ARRAY, sizeof(char), NR_CHARS, stdout);
```